# Navigate to day in Sharepoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-2010

is there a way to go to a Calendar in sharepoint but in the Day view to an especific day? using c#?,

I see that always is the link to http://user-pc/Lists/Calendario/calendar.aspx, and the default is the month view, I need to go to the day view of an specific day provided by user.

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `CalendarDate` and `CalendarPeriod` query string parameters:

```
http://user-pc/Lists/Calendario/calendar.aspx?CalendarDate=2011-11-02&CalendarPeriod=day
```

More information: [Specifying the "Start Date" and "Calendar Period" in the URL to a SharePoint calendar using Out-of-the-Box functionality](http://thedotnetter.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/specifying-the-start-date-and-time-period-in-the-url-to-a-sharepoint-calendar-using-out-of-the-box-functionality/)